# how stacks are formed and value from a method return when the method has TWO recursive calls of itself from within itself

Tags: recursion, stack

I have tried creating stacks for recursive inorder,preorder,postoreder traversal for binary tree and I was doing it pretty well. In other cases like, for example, for a test case my answer should be 'true',say.And, for example,

```
boolean method(root)
{
  // more code
  method(root.left());
  method(root.right());
}
```

,somewhere,the call of method(root.left()) returns false  and a call of method(root.right()) returns true that should be our answer. But since call of method(root.left() ) completes first and somewhere, in between it's execution, it might have returned false. then how do we get our result true from method(root.right())?? I think it is related to how stacks are formed and values from a method are returned when recursive calls ,in this way, happen.Explain it and correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Whoever marked this question  -1 ,  could have answered at least and directed me to post it somewhere else if the problem shouldn't be posted  over here..(Take it positively!)

Comment: You need to return something.. Perhaps `return method(root.left())||method(root.right());`. If you need to process more you use local variables but without doing anything with the result you cannot make it work. Your basecase(s) needs return as well.

Comment: @Sylwester I I accept it as my fault .I have commented that(base case) as "more code" that means there the base case statement lies .

Comment: @Sylwester assuming that there is a base case , would explain how things  that I have asked for are happening in the background!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return values. The method need to make use of the returned values in its logic to stop/continue the search.

You need to have that the base cases return either true of false. Then when doing the first recursive call you need only do the first if the result is true. The second recursive call would be the result of the method if it's needed. Thus you are looking at something like this:

```java
boolean method(root)
{
  if( root == null ) { // base case 1
     return false;
  }
  if( root.value == someValue ) { // base case 2, what should be a positive
     return true;
  }
  // default search left first and return true if true
  if( method(root.left()) ) {
     return true;
  }
  // default search right and return true if true
  if( method(root.right()) ){
     return true;
  }
  // return false since neither recursive calls were true
  return false;
}
```

This is very verbose and can be written like this instead:

```java
boolean method(root)
{
  return root != null && ( root.value == someValue ||
                           method(root.left())   ||
                           method(root.right()));
}
```

I find the last more readable but novices might find the more verbose first one to be more clear.

In both the callee resumes operation after the first recursive call (which might have had it's share of calls as well) and continues it's logic and recurses on the right side if needed.

Don't care about the system stack. Care about the base case and test them. Then do the simplest of added complexity to do the default case so that you see the problem becoming smaller in the recursive call(s). It's much better going from simple to more complex than to try figuring this stuff out by starting at a large tree looking at whats happening  with a very deep recursive round.

Comment: thank you sir! your answer is helpful and easy to understand.